# Vue - how to loop through values in array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-select

Is there a way to use a `v-select` to display the values of an array? I need to list the `str` values of this array:

```
myArr: [
            { key: 'one', str: '1st' },
            { key: 'two', str: '2nd' },
            { key: 'three', str: '3rd' },
            { key: 'four', str: '4th' }
]
```

in the `v-select` but can't figure out how to do it. So far I've got this working:

```
<v-select v-model="vCase.eligibility" :items="eligPeriods[0].str"></v-select>
```

It displays "1st" in the `v-select`. But I need all the values to display.

I tried using a template:

```
<template v-slot:myArr="{item}">
        <v-select v-model="myVar.selectedVal" :items="item[str]"></v-select>
</template>
```

but then it doesn't even render on the page.

Any help or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an associative array as items you will need to do something like this

```
<v-select :options="myArr" :reduce="item => item.key" label="item.str" />
```

You can read more about it [here](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting)